# "calls" made during compilation?

Tags: java, bytecode, instrumentation, java-bytecode-asm, jvm-crash

```
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  Internal Error (javaCalls.cpp:64), pid=3560, tid=140207058839296
#  guarantee(!thread->is_Compiler_thread()) failed: cannot make java calls from the compiler
#
# JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (7.0_65-b17) (build 1.7.0_65-b17)
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (24.65-b04 mixed mode linux-amd64 compressed oops)
```

The error eventually turned out to be that I had forgotten one `pop` instruction before throwing an exception. (Last instruction before throwing the Exception was a `checkcast` that had succeeded, and Java didn't like its result still being on the stack.)

[Also (should be obvious, but I realise my words can be confusing): no exception was thrown during execution of the faulty code (because the code was still being compiled and not executed), but the next instructions after the `checkcast` would amount to throwing an Exception.]

I'm curious, though, how that results in this error message,

```
cannot make java calls from the compiler
```

What kind of "call" would the compiler think it's trying to make?

Comment: This message is produce here: https://github.com/JetBrains/jdk8u_hotspot/blob/master/src/share/vm/runtime/javaCalls.cpp. This may helps you.

Comment: I don’t get it. The result of a `checkcast` instruction is the same object reference as before, just with a different, usually more specific, type. If it’s not the throwable you’re going to throw, why cast it, or if it is the throwable, why `pop` it, and anyway, if the type doesn’t match, shouldn’t the verifier reject it? If invalid code passes the verifier, be it a bug or explicit turning off, there is no point in discussing subsequent JVM crashes.

Comment: @Holger it's part of a series of typechecks. For some types, I want to throw a dedicated exception (that will be caught and handled further up), for others, I want to do something type-specific with the object I just cast, instead.

Comment: That still doesn’t explain it. All that `checkcast` followed by `pop` would to, is to throw a `ClassCastException` if the type doesn’t match. If you place that directly before throwing an exception, you are throwing an exception in either case, not “do something type-specific with the object”. And well, `athrow` requires a throwable on the stack. Pushing the throwable before the `checkcast` makes no sense, but when you’re pushing it after the `checkcast`, it is entirely irrelevant whether there are additional items on the stack.